# Goodman GMP 100-4 Red light blinks 4 times

Tags: blower

As the heading says I bought a used Goodman GMP 100-4 and the red light on the board blinks 4 times.  As soon as power is turned on tho the Furnace I hear a click and a few seconds later the blower motor and inducer run even with the thermostat disconnected.  I have checked the inductor switch and have continuity, and also tried jumping it.  I checked the nipple on the inductor and it is clear, the hose is not kinked.  The vacuum pot does open and close when vacuum is applied.  the fuse on the board is good.  I did not see a reset button any where.  Also there is a multi connection plug laying in the bottom of the Furnace and I have no idea what it is for.  See photo I just happen to think I have not checked the igniter.  It will do the same with the thermostat connect or out of circuit.  Am I missing something,  is the board the problem. [image]applied.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A better picture might help, but the fact that the furnace runs with no thermostat seems key.

Comment: sorry about the bad photo,  best I can do right know

Comment: 4 blinks on a Goodman means open high limit, which would explain why the blowers are running. Check the board, as there's likely a place for that connector to plug in.  Plugging that into the proper spot might fix the problem.

Comment: Check the over temp sensor on the fire box. These are usually a round disk about the size of a 50c coin with 2 connections and a small manual reset that needs to be pushed to reset. If this is the problem the fire box over heated some times not a issue but if it trips again there is a problem. Over temp can be caused by several problems and a service call may be needed with more than 1 reset needed.

Comment: I checked everything I could, the igniter is good I jumped all the little round sensors,  and traced all the wiring.  All I found is a round sensor in the back of the blower cage. Tracing the wires one wire goes back to the limiter and the other wire goes back to the multi connection plug that is laying loose.  Am I missing a board or something?  I have more and better photo's but can't figure out how to attach them to this comment

Comment: Does anyone know what the plug laying in the bottom is for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [superfluous](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/what-should-be-done-about-abandoned-questions-that-will-likely-never-be-answered?cb=1) because once the connector was plugged back into the control board it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The plug in bottom of the furnace had come unplugged from the board.  Plugging it back in solved the problem.

Comment: Same thing happened to me!  I know someone closed your question, but for what it's worth it really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

That plugs into the board shown. 
Have you checked the heat exchanger in that thing? They had issues from the factory. Odds are you bought a paperweight with that furnace.

Comment: Heat exchanger looks OK,  I'll have to look harder,,didn't see a place on the board. But tri focals make things hard to see unless you tip your head just right

Comment: Those heat exchangers usually split at the bottom right above the blower. You'd have to pull the blower and look up into it to see, or pull the exchanger.

Comment: Took the board off and found the spot for the plug.  Plugged it in and problem solved.